# Missing some .dll files in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, qt, dll

ssleay32.dll
zlib1.dll
libeay32.dll

So I'm missing the above .dll files in PostgreSQL 10.11-3 windows 32bit version. I don't know if I'm missing any more .dll files because I'm new to this database.I'm trying to connect with Qt so I need these .dll files to copy separately in qt sqldrivers since currently it's throwing an error "QPSQL driver not loaded" but it shows the driver in available drivers.

anyone has the same problem of found a solution please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libpq.dll and other dlls from a PostgreSQL distribution are required plus qsqlpsql.dll in sqldrivers subdir in order to connect with QSqlDatabase